# How Can I Reset User Password Using Django Class Based Views with Gmail Account

Tags: python, django, gmail

I want to implement a User Reset Password functionality in my Django application and I am getting this error : SMTPConnectError at /password_reset/

(421, b'Service not available').
I have done everything on my Gmail account by setting the 2 Steps Verification and Application Password which I used in my Django settings for the email.
Here is my urls code:

```
path('password_reset/', auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset'),
path('password_reset_done/', auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name ='password_reset_done'),
path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset_password_complete/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_complete'),
```

Here is my setting.py code for the email:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT =  587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_googlemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_gmail_account_app_password'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Support Team <noreply@support.org>'
```

Thanks in anticipation to your solutions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to to enable allow less secure app feature under account security settings.
You can click [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) to enable this feature.

Hope this help you

Comment: you may wish to note that Gmail does not use allow less secured app feature again as of 30th May 2022 but are using 2 steps verification with application password which must be done. You may also wish to note that I have done all that as stated clearly in my question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.
Ensure you have a strong internet connection. I had this problem some time ago